# Unirest Java POST request for Intercom API return error 500

Tags: java, unirest, intercom

I'm currently trying to do a POST request on [Intercom API](https://api.intercom.io/conversations/search) using [unirest](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/) for java and It returns a server error 500 but when I do the same request with Postman it returns my desired results.

Sample code:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

HttpResponse response = Unirest
              .post("https://api.intercom.io/conversations/search")
              .headers(headers)
              .body(requestBody)
              .asObject(HashMap.class);
```

This is my request body

```
private Map<String, Object> getQueryValues(String field, String operator, Object value) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("field", field);
    map.put("operator", operator);
    map.put("value", value);

    return map;
}

private Map<String, Object> getRequestBody() {
    List<Map<String, Object>> value = new ArrayList<>();
    value.add(getQueryValues("updated_at", ">", 1590278400));
    value.add(getQueryValues("source.delivered_as", "=", "admin_initiated"));

    Map<String, Object> query = new HashMap<>();
    query.put("operator", "AND");
    query.put("value", value);

    Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
    requestBody.put("query", query);

    return requestBody;
}
```

Comment: If you print out the body when you get error 500, what do you get?

Comment: @libanbn this one {
 "query":  {
    "operator": "AND",
    "value": [
       {
  "field": "updated_at",
     "operator": ">",
     "value": 1590278400
   }, 
      {
        "field": "source.delivered_as",
        "operator": "=",
        "value": "admin_initiated"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to be my UNIX date long value wherein the correct value should be the Epoch seconds. So from `myDate.getTime()` I changed it to `myDate.toInstant().getEpochSecond()`.